# Storing do.call("grid.arrange") output without printing

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I would like to create a variable p that contains a plot with four ggplot2 subplots. I am able to achieve this with the below code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
data = diamonds[1:50,]
x = data$x
myPlots = lapply(c(1,5,6,7), function(i){
  y = as.data.frame(data[,i])
  y = y[,1]
  df = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
  p <- qplot(x, y, data=df)
  p
})

p = do.call("grid.arrange", c(myPlots, ncol=2))
```

I like that I can use the variable p later by calling:

```
library(grid)
grid.draw(p)
```

However, I do not like that when I initially create p with the `do.call("grid.arrange")` syntax, it plots it automatically (at least in RStudio).

My question is: Is it possible to create p to be stored for later use, without plotting it upon its creation?

Comment: Does this happen if you replace `"grid.arrange"` with `"arrangeGrob"`?

Comment: ps no need for `do.call` anymore: `arrangeGrob(grobs=myPlots, ncol=2)`

Comment: Thank you! Both of your solutions work!

Comment: Hmmm neither of these work for me sadly, using R markdown in R Studio. grid.arrange is always printing the output before I can process it through cowplot/store as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

For the life of me I couldn't figure out how to stop this from happening using `grid.arrange`/`gridExtra`/`arrangeGrob`. I had to use `fig.hide` in the R Markdown chunk header, and then put the subsequent output commands into a different chunk.

````
```{r, fig.show='hide'}
````

The resulting output of `grid.arrange()` is still displayed when code is executed, but it doesn't end up in the knitted report.

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/hide-one.html